# How can I have an html element stay visible on the page within the bounds of another html object?

Tags: html, scroll, movable

I have a list of reports on a page. I currently have 4 large buttons on the right to view, add, edit or delete a button. We've had complaints about people having to scroll back up to click on the buttons once they've selected a report because they have soo many.

Is there a way to have an html object like a div, stay visible on the page when you scroll it? But within the bounds of the container of the grid?

Thanks

Comment: I think what you are looking for are frames, I haven't worked with them much so I'm not comfortable giving an example, but google them and see if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the buttons or their container position:fixed through CSS? Another way could be to use the onscroll Javascript event to move them or their container.